# Data integrity before migration

Tags: svn, perforce, integrity

I have to migrate 1.5TB of data from a Subversion to a perforce server.

Is there any tool I can use to check if there is errors in the files?

Comment: I would leave the data in subversion and start from today with perforce.  Old data can be checked in subversion and new projects and code can be viewed through perforce.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check out [this section](http://info.perforce.com/Subversion-to-Perforce-Migration-TY.html) on Perforce's website. You should also check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250905/svn-to-perforce-migration).